# まめつぶ used as a counter?

Tags: grammar, nouns

> *あのイヌ　げいじゅつかのつもりらしいけど。。。アイデアがうかばないみたい。
>
> ＊のうみそが　**まめつぶ　ぐらいしかない**んだから　ムリもないわよね。

Grammatically (or something), I think まめつぶ works like a quantifier that appears as a noun but I'm not really sure about what I'm talking about.

> ＊のうみそが一つぐらいしかないんだから、ムリもないわよね

If that's the case, are there any other nouns similar to まめつぶ?

Comment: So the first line is quoted from somewhere? Where did you get the second line from? Did you just replace まめつぶ with 一つ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> のうみそがまめつぶぐらいしかない

It means the dog's のうみそ is so small as まめつぶ. You could rephrase it as のうみそがまめつぶくらいの大きさしかない.

[豆粒]{まめつぶ} is used to talk about the size of something, often to say how small something is. Eg:

> 展望台からは、地上の車が豆粒のように見えました。

Words used like this include: [米粒]{こめつぶ}, [小豆]{あずき}, [拳]{こぶし}, [親指]{おやゆび}, [小指]{こゆび}, ピンポン[玉]{だま}, テニスボール ...

> ピンポン玉くらいを手のひらにとり、お顔全体に広げます。
> 米粒ほどの量をレンズの裏表に塗って、やわらかい布で拭きとってください。

Most of these words can be used with a suffix [大]{だい}, like this:

> [拳大]{こぶしだい}の唐揚げ
> [米粒大]{こめつぶだい}のしこり
> [小豆大]{あずきだい}の発疹